# How to show different Nginx helm error page

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I have an nginx ingress helm chart at my k8s cluster.

I sometimes got some problems with my pods and then we are getting 503 error from the ingress.

I want that if there is nginx error to show a different page.
there is a way i can point from the error to show a page from a different url? or maybe show a different html page?

Thanks